# spring cloud gateway not working for an unkonwn reason even after using static and dynamic rounting

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, gateway

I have added a gateway to my microservices that I developped using spring cloud.
The problem is that It doesn't work whatever the routing's type I use: Static or dynamic.
Here is the classes I am using:

Gateway:

```java
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class GatewayApplication {
    // adding Routes statically
    /*@Bean
    RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder){
        return builder.routes()
                .route(r -> r.path("/company/**").uri("lb://COMPANY-SERVICE"))
                .build();
    }*/

    /*@Bean
    RouteLocator gatewayRoutes (RouteLocatorBuilder builder){
        return builder.routes()
                .route(r->r.path("/countries/**")
                        .filters(f->f
                                .rewritePath("/countries/(?<segment>.*)","/v3.1/${segment}")
                        )
                        .uri("https://restcountries.com")
                )
                .route(r->r.path("/muslimsalat/**")
                        .filters(f->f
                                .rewritePath("/muslimsalat/(?<segment>.*)","/v1/${segment}")
                        )
                        .uri("https://api.aladhan.com")
                )
                .build();
    }*/

    /*@Bean
    RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder){
        return builder.routes()
                .route(r -> r.path("/cours/**")
                        .filters(f -> f.stripPrefix(1))
                        .uri("http://localhost:8082/api/cours/"))
                .route(r -> r.path("/etudiants/**")
                        .filters(f -> f.stripPrefix(1))
                        .uri("http://localhost:8081/api/etudiants/"))
                .build();
    }*/

    /*@Bean
    DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator gatewayDynamicRoutes(
            ReactiveDiscoveryClient rdc,
            DiscoveryLocatorProperties dlp) {
        return new DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator(rdc, dlp);
    }*/

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.yml

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: r1
          uri: http://localhost:8082/api/cours
          predicates:
            - Path=/cours/**
        - id: r2
          uri: lb://ETUDIANT-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/etudiants/**
  application:
    name: gateway

server:
  port: 8080

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

I don't have problems with other microservices Discovery clients... Everything is working fine when I try to access the Rest APIs by their original endpoints. But when trying to access them using gateway, I run to this errors:
Using dynamic routing doesn't work neither:

application.properties(cours-service):

```
spring.application.name=cours-service

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cours
spring.datasource.username=xxxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxxx
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

#Port
server.port=8082

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

and etc
When I run the gateway using the debugging mode, it shows this in the console:

```
2023-12-09T16:41:33.254+02:00 DEBUG 9576 --- [gateway] [ctor-http-nio-3] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Mapping [Exchange: GET http://localhost:8080/COURS-SERVICE] to Route{id='ReactiveCompositeDiscoveryClient_COURS-SERVICE', uri=lb://COURS-SERVICE, order=0, predicate=Paths: [/COURS-SERVICE/**], match trailing slash: true, gatewayFilters=[[[RewritePath /COURS-SERVICE/?(?<remaining>.*) = '/${remaining}'], order = 1]], metadata={management.port=8082}}
2023-12-09T16:41:33.254+02:00 DEBUG 9576 --- [gateway] [ctor-http-nio-3] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : [2cc212d9-1] Mapped to org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler@753e04a6
2023-12-09T16:41:33.255+02:00 DEBUG 9576 --- [gateway] [ctor-http-nio-3] o.s.c.g.handler.FilteringWebHandler      : Sorted gatewayFilterFactories: [[GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RemoveCachedBodyFilter@10817f46}, order = -2147483648], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.AdaptCachedBodyGlobalFilter@224d86d2}, order = -2147482648], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter@6885ed19}, order = -1], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardPathFilter@d8835af}, order = 0], [[RewritePath /COURS-SERVICE/?(?<remaining>.*) = '/${remaining}'], order = 1], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.RouteToRequestUrlFilter@2d4a3e13}, order = 10000], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ReactiveLoadBalancerClientFilter@50e5032c}, order = 10150], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.LoadBalancerServiceInstanceCookieFilter@545d2560}, order = 10151], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WebsocketRoutingFilter@16681017}, order = 2147483646], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.NettyRoutingFilter@124eb83d}, order = 2147483647], [GatewayFilterAdapter{delegate=org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ForwardRoutingFilter@4a22e4d7}, order = 2147483647]]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svpNa.png)

I tried the debugging mode, the static routnig using application.yml and Beans but nothing works

Comment: What URL are you requesting from gateway and what URL works directly on the service?